# FireFox css transition 'transition-all' creates flicker on hover and other unexpected occasions

Tags: css, firefox, transition

I am wondering why I am seeing a flickering effect on an element when using `transition: all 0.5s ease-out;` in FireFox (latest as of this writing). It's hard to explain, but see live example here: http://imaginary-material.launchpage.me/ (check out the logo flickering) - this issue does not happen on Safari or Chrome.

#### update

In my original code I had the transitions applied to the `a` tag wrapping the `img` and the `img`. Removing the `translate` from the `a` tag gets rid of the flicker, so that solves my problem. However that is still a mystery to me, if anyone cares to comment on why it would cause flicker, please do so.

Comment: Try removing double transition. One is on link, another is on image. Remove from link

Comment: Hi, I did try that and it seems to solve the flickering, however, I don't think it's a matter of "doubling" the transition effects, because if I remove it from the image and keep it on the link, it still flickers...

Comment: Your link has hover effect, that is somehow related to transition

Comment: Seems like a logical thing to assume, but note, the flickering happens when not interacting with the element at all (hovering). Like when you scroll down the page, the parent element is shrunk, the logo flickers. Considering that Safari and Chrome don't have this issue, is this a bug with FireFox?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution you are using Very big images [1024 resolution] instead of thumbnails!

**Use light images for flicker-less transitions!**

Try this for images `src="http://placekitten.com/120/120"` demo it will not flicker! Checked

Comment: The logo image is 125px by 125px, that's the flickering image. I don't think the size is an issue...